# How to use SMOTE to rebalance multiclass dataset when the target is one hot encoded with pd.get_dummies?

Tags: class-imbalance, smote, one-hot-encoding, oversampling

I'm using a multiclass dataset (cic-ids-2017), which is very imbalanced. I have already encoded the categorical feature (which is the `target`) using `OneHotEncoder`.
I tried to use `SMOTE` oversampling method to balance the data with pipeline:

```
X = df.drop(['Label'],1)
y = df.Label

steps = [('onehot', OneHotEncoder()), ('smt', SMOTE())]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=steps)

X, y = pipeline.fit_resample(X, y)
```

When I used pd.get_dummies instead of `OneHotEncoder`, in this case I could not use the pipeline (because of `get_dummies`).

How can I balance the dataset using `SMOTE` ? (and use `get_dummies` for One Hot Encoding)

Comment: There is a prerequisite i.e. _Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods_. So, It will not work. Why you want to do that.

Comment: I used get_dummies beacause, OneHotEncoder() of Scikit generate me NAN. I tried to use SMOTE without Pipeline, but does not work. for that I tried also the Pipeline